# Alternative to returning in loop after exception is thrown

Tags: asp.net-core, try-catch, goto

Hello i was wondering what would be a good/optimal approach if i am running a continous loop that i want it guarded with a `try-catch` clause,but as soon as the exception is thrown i want to go back to the loop.More specifically the loop is taking data from a socket,and then i put the data in a database.I do not want to close the socket if the database throws exception.

**Current Version**:

```
while(true){
  try
  {
   socket.ReadAsync(....)
   ----database operation that can throw---
   socket.SendAsync(....)
  }
  catch
  {
    ---socket.SendAsync(--cause of error on db--)
  }
}
```

As you can see this version always enters the `try-catch` block.

I was thinking of using a `goto` statement

```
` 
  try
  {
   //goto label
   while(true){
   socket.ReadAsync(....)
   ----database operation that can throw---
   socket.SendAsync(....)
   }
  }
  catch
  {
    ---socket.SendAsync(--cause of error on db--);
    goto --back in loop
  }
}
```

Is there any issue with performance ?Would the `goto` version be faster?

Comment: `try except` is very *cheap* providing that no exception has been thrown. There's no need to switch to `goto` version

Comment: So is there no performance difference in having a global `try-catch` on the `while` (with a `goto`)  vs having the `try-catch` at every while iteration?

Comment: it's the `catch` that consumes resources (performing stack trace on exception throwing and catching), `try` itself doesn't deserve `goto` optimisation (miniscule gain if any, great loss in readability)